# Increment or decrement a value in react array while mapping

Tags: arrays, reactjs, array-map, ecma

```
  export default class Cart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedForCart: [],
      checkOut: true,
      priceQuantity: undefined,
      total: undefined,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        {this.state.selectedForCart &&
          this.state.selectedForCart.map((v, i) => {
            return (
              <Container className="mt-5" key={i}>
                <Row>
                  <Col lg={2} md={2} sm={12}>
                    <p>
                      Price:&emsp;&#8377;
                      {v.priceTaxIncluded}
                    </p>
                    <p style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}>Tax inclusive</p>
                  </Col>

                  <Col lg={2} md={2} sm={12}>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Form.Label>Quantity</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="number"
                        placeholder="Quantity"
                        value={1}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                           this.setState({
                           priceQuantity: e.target.value

                           });
                          console.log(v.priceTaxIncluded * e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Col>
                  <Col lg={2} md={2} sm={12}>
                    {this.state.checkOut && (
                      <>
                        <p>{this.state.priceQuantity}</p>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Container>
            );
          })}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here in the above code, I'm mapping an array of items from the state object "" value. And if I increment a specific item, then that specific item's quantity only should increment. But it is not happening all items are getting incremented. And also the price should be multiplied with the incremented value and should be shown...

Thank You.

[As in this image, I'm changing the quantity. But If I change the quantity of a product, then its reflecting the price for all products. As I have only one state object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl18Z.png)

Comment: The state which you setting in onChange, where you are accessing it? Also while mapping provide key to parent element ie. Container else React won't understand which row you are changing.

Comment: @Rohitha Sir/Madam, I have updated the code, can you please check it? I'm accessing the state in p tag

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the priceQuantity to input value. Then conditionally render in last column. As you are trying to print priceQuantity in last column it will show for all rows.

```
 this.state = {
      ...
      priceQuantity: 0,
      ..
    };

{this.state.selectedForCart &&
          this.state.selectedForCart.map((v, i) => {
            return (
              <Container className="mt-5" key={i}>
                <Row>
                  <Col lg={2} md={2} sm={12}>
                    <p>
                      Price:&emsp;&#8377;
                      {v.priceTaxIncluded}
                    </p>
                    <p style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}>Tax inclusive</p>
                  </Col>

                  <Col lg={2} md={2} sm={12}>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Form.Label>Quantity</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="number"
                        placeholder="Quantity"
                        value={this.state.priceQuantity}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                           this.setState({
                           priceQuantity: e.target.value

                           });
                          console.log(v.priceTaxIncluded * e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Col>
                  <Col lg={2} md={2} sm={12}>
                    {this.state.checkOut && (
                      <>
                        <p>{this.state.priceQuantity ? v.priceTaxIncluded * this.state.priceQuantity : 0}</p>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Container>
            );
          })}
```

Comment: sir please check the image which i have uploaded. It is still showing like same

Comment: Can you add your code to codesandbox, it would be easier to check.